# Adding user from root shell

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have only a guest account. I go to recovery mode and try to use `adduser` but it gives me error code 10. I also have try to `sudo remove etc/group.lock` and `etc/gshadow.lock`. It still gives me error code 10.

What should I do now?

Comment: can you add more detail about your error?

Comment: Since you're in recovery mode, you will need to remount the root filesystem to make it writeable - did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The notice will be something like this:

```
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 1000 user' returned error code 10. Exiting.
```

Check if you have any of these 2 files

```
/etc/group.lock 
/etc/gshadow.lock
```

Remove them (or copy them to a backup) and redo the `adduser`. Linux locks these files to stop two or more from editing the same file